# To change Paid app to Free App Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I have Developer account in Google Play and published an App as Paid App. Now i need to change the Paid app to Free App. How can I do the same?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for you to ask about _programming_ stuff, not google play. Your question have nothing to do with programming

Comment: You can change a paid app to free app ,But you can't change it back to again a paid app

Answer (score 4):

If you publish your app as a priced app, you can change it at any time to be a free app (but cannot then change it back to priced). You can also sell in-app products and subscriptions.

To change an app from priced to free:

1. Sign in to your [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).
2. Click **All applications**.
3. Select an app.
4. On the left menu, click **Pricing & Distribution**.
5. Under **Pricing & Distribution**, click the **Free** button.
6. Near the top of your screen, click **Save draft** (new apps) or **Submit update** (existing apps).

References: https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html#decide-price 
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138412

Answer (score 0):

To change an app from price to free.

1. SignIn your **Google play developer console**.
2. Click All Applications.
3. select an App.
4. On the left menu, click on **Production** tab (under **Monetize** section).
5. Click on **App pricing**.
6. In the 'Pricing' section, next to 'Your app is', click **Make your app free** or **Make your app paid**.

References: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6334373?visit_id=638175645599412080-1877633936&rd=1#paid_free